# Error paginador con php, mysql y bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, paginación

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de realizar un paginador, utilizando lo mencionado en el titulo. Funciona pero solo me da como resultado que el total de las paginas es 1, cuando evidentemente deberían ser mas. dejo los códigos necesarios para ver si me pueden ayudar...

```
 <?php
        include("componentes/recursos.php");
        $limit = 5;
        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;           
        $mostrarprod = $producto->listar_productos($start,$limit);
        $pages = ceil(count($mostrarprod) / $limit);
        for($i=0;$i<count($mostrarprod); $i++){

  ?>
```

En el código anterior lo que estoy realizando es el for para mostrar los productos, pero a su vez estoy poniendo el limite de productos por consulta, trayendo el id de pagina en caso de que no le haya y contando la cantidad de paginas que debería hacer.

```
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
 <?php for( $i = 1; $i<= $pages; $i++) :?>
 <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="market.php?page=<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></a></li>
 <?php endfor; ?>
 <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
```

En este ultimo estoy realizando el for para agregar la cantidad de paginas y los respectivos href,etc. pero sin importar la cantidad de registros siempre tiene 1 pagina. probé accediendo de forma "manual"(escribiendo en la url la page 2) a la siguiente pagina y funciona pero no estaría funcionando para mostrar el botón para las demás paginas. espero haberme expresado bien! gracias de ante manos!

Clase para listar producto:

```
class Producto{
public $base;

function __construct($baseconectada){
    $this->base = $baseconectada;
}
public function listar_productos($start, $limit){
    $SQL = $this->base->ejecutarSQL("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY Name_Prod LIMIT $start,$limit");
    return $SQL;
}}
```

Clase de la base de datos:

```
<?php
class BaseDatos {
    private $conexion;

    function __construct($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $base){
        $this->conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $pass, $base);
    }

    public function ejecutarSQL($codigoSQL){
        $instrSQL = strtoupper(substr($codigoSQL, 0,6));

        switch($instrSQL){
            case 'INSERT':
            case 'UPDATE':
            case 'DELETE':
                $consultaSQL =$this->conexion->query($codigoSQL);
                break;
            case 'SELECT':
                $consultaSQL =$this->conexion->query($codigoSQL);
                /* para mostrar los datos */
                $mostrarDatos=[];
                while($listarDatos = $consultaSQL->fetch_assoc()){
                    $mostrarDatos[] = $listarDatos;
                }
                return $mostrarDatos;
                break;

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema parece estar en cómo estás calculando el total de páginas. En tu código, estás utilizando `count($mostrarprod)` para obtener el número total de productos y luego dividiéndolo por el límite para calcular las páginas. Sin embargo, esto puede no ser preciso, ya que estás obteniendo solo una porción de los productos en cada consulta.

En lugar de contar la cantidad de productos devueltos, puedes realizar otra consulta para obtener el número total de productos sin aplicar límites. Luego, puedes calcular el número de páginas utilizando esa información. Aquí hay una modificación de tu código para lograr esto:

```
<?php
include("componentes/recursos.php");

$limit = 5;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

// Obtener el total de productos sin límites
$totalProductos = $producto->obtenerTotalProductos();

// Calcular el número total de páginas
$pages = ceil($totalProductos / $limit);

// Obtener los productos para la página actual
$mostrarprod = $producto->listar_productos($start, $limit);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($mostrarprod); $i++) {
    // Tu código para mostrar los productos
}

// Tu código para generar los enlaces de paginación
?>
```

Ahora tu clase producto

```
class Producto{
public $base;

function __construct($baseconectada){
    $this->base = $baseconectada;
}
public function listar_productos($start, $limit){
    $SQL = $this->base->ejecutarSQL("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY Name_Prod LIMIT $start,$limit");
    return $SQL;
}}
public function obtenerTotalProductos() {
        $result = $this->base->ejecutarSQL("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM productos");
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        return $row['total'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo probé, pero ahora me da un error nuevo.
` Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\market\componentes\listarproducto.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\market\market.php(78): Producto->obtenerTotalProductos() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\market\componentes\listarproducto.php on line 14`
Creo que se debe a que mi función de mostra prod en la clase de base de datos, ya que tengo lo siguiente: (lo envio en otro coment porque no entra)

Comment: Lo agregue a la pregunta porque era demasiado largo

Comment: Hice unas modificaciones en el código que pasaste, en la funcion obtenertotalproductos elimine el $row y puse return $result['total'] pero me dice: ***Undefined array key "total"***

Comment: lo solucione añadiendo un [0] al array quedo  return $result[0]['total'], gracias!